# Which express edition to use for ASP.NET web apps in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Which Express edition is best suitable for starting ASP.NET web applications in C#? I imagine Visual Web Developer Express is designed for this, but what about Visual C# Express?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For web dev / practice, I would recommend [Visual Web Developer Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/download/), [Visual Studio Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/express/download/), and [SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/sql/default.aspx).  With SQL express, you can create MDF files in your app_code folder in your web app.  You will probably do the majority of your web development in Web Dev Express.  However, it is useful to have VS Express installed as well.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/beginner/default.aspx) is a good source of info for starting out with these apps.

Answer (score 2):

Visual C# can support WPF Browser application. Other than that, it is not going to support any kind of web development.